# Validate given culture date isvalid or invalid in javascript function

Tags: javascript

My application has to support multi language when change the culture date my function is not working 
I need a method should accept any date format and   return given date is valid or invalid in java script  at

I tried  Local date & New date methods but it return always true

```
if (new Date(date)
    alert('valid');
else
    alert('In valid');
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: You may want to provide some more context on your application, some example of what you are trying to do, some code of what you have tried so far. In general your question needs more effort. Please update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.parse(date)`;

It will give you `NaN` if date is invalid. Else it will return the timestamp.

> **Date.parse()** returns a **timestamp**, an *integer representing the number
>   of milliseconds since 01/Jan/1970.* It will return `NaN` if it cannot
>   parse the supplied date string.

```
var timestamp = Date.parse('foo')
if (isNaN(timestamp) == false)
{
     var d = new Date(timestamp);
}
```